# Magento: Add Custom Attribute to Order Grid

Tags: magento

I have a custom attribute in my product that i want it to appears in the orders grid, the attribute is added to mg_catalog_product_flat_1 table but when i try to make the above join i get an error, all other built in attributes like name, sku works fine so how can i get this done

Please check my code below

```
$collection->join(
                'sales/order_item',
                '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',

                array(

                    'Productid'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.product_id SEPARATOR ",")'),
                    //'manufacturer'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.manufacturer_value SEPARATOR ",")'),
                    'name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                    )

                );

        $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

        parent::setCollection($collection);
```

---

```
$this->addColumn('manufacturer', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('manufacturer'),
            'width'     => '100px',
            'index'     => 'manufacturer',
            'type'        => 'text',

        ));
```

---

If i uncomment manufacturer part i get an error a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An item is not the equivalent of a product. If you want to get attribute of a product in an item, you need to call the $item->getProduct() function to be able to get all the attributes of the product that are not defined in the item.

Then, you need to apply it to your collection. To do that, you can use the function walk of the collection object to apply a function on each element. The problem, in my opinion, is that you need to loop over you collection of order and then on the collection of items to get the attribute you need.

Another solution is to follow the recommandation of [custom prdoduct's attribute to quote/order item](http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/). This mean the attribute will be added to all items all the time but will be avaiable like sku...

Hope it helps,